# Terminal does not work after running rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, terminal

after running "rails server" on my mac to start my application, my terminal does not allow me to write commands in the terminal. All I get is the following, with the problem that I can not write any commands.

```
Last login: Mon Jan  2 13:19:07 on ttys001
Nicholass-MacBook-Pro:~ nicholaswenzel$ cd last_test
Nicholass-MacBook-Pro:last_test nicholaswenzel$ cd nofuckingidea
Nicholass-MacBook-Pro:nofuckingidea nicholaswenzel$ rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.6 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2017-01-02 13:23:18] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-01-02 13:23:18] INFO  ruby 2.2.3 (2015-08-18) [x86_64-darwin15]
[2017-01-02 13:23:18] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=8743 port=3000
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: use another tab

Comment: @nikita can you provide more info.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start your server in a background:

```
rails server &
```

But, usually, this problem can be resolving by starting an additional terminal process (open new terminal window or tab). In this case, you'll be able to see server logs in runtime.